# Why does Mozilla addons downthemall cause to a download URL to appear hitting multiple times?

Tags: php, download, mozilla

I develop a PHP code and count how much data was downloaded by the client. My code is working fine if someone directly requests my file from a browser.

But if someone installs a Mozilla extensions like ‘’downthemall’’ and then the URL is requested by that extension then it requests the file URL 4 times so I get the downloaded data 4 times.

How do I fix this? The same happened when the user is using jDownloader software or any software.

Comment: Because it's hitting multiple times. Download accelerator create multiple requests simultaneously. Alternatively you can require cookies on download, include the unique ID on the download stat, and only count each stat with unique ID. By the way, what will be calculated by your code if someone start the download and cancel it midway?

Answer (score 0):

You can modify your Php download script so it supports the different downloaders. For example try to save the HTTP request headers and URL parameters sent by the different download clients